# Azure SQL Managed Instance run Automation Account's notebooks

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have a notebook in an Azure Automation Account that I would like to call from SQL Managed Instance. Normally what I would do is to run:

```
Start-AzAutomationRunbook `
    -AutomationAccountName "some-aa-name" `
    -Name "notebook-name" `
    -ResourceGroupName "rg-name" `
    -Wait
```

My idea was to run it with a SQL Agent with a PowerShell task type. However, running it gives me an error:

> The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'The term
> 'Start-AzAutomationRunbook' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
> name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again.

Is there any way to make this cmdlet work on the managed instance?

Side note: I tested calling a WebHook and it works. However, it is not a very secure solution and it doesn't have the ability to wait for the completion.